# Android ListView addFooterView() issue

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView which is getting populated from service response. When service is called i am showing a progressbar by adding footerview by inflating progressbar view and hiding it once listview is populated.

**Note**: I am adding footerview before setting adapter. Then i am adding footerview at each service call.

**problem**: when service returns non empty response everything is working fine(footerview is shown and hided after listview is populated)
when service response is empty i.e. listview is empty in next method calls to addFooterView() not working(not showing footerview).

Following is sample code

```
addFooterView(loadingView, null, false);
m_List.addAll(listItems);
m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
removeFooterView(loadingView);
```

**Note**: If each time list size is greater than zero i am not facing problem.

Comment: when `listItems` is empty.. it will add and remove footer in a fraction of second where you wont come to know that was really displayed and disappeared...

Comment: @skadoosh but on new service call when listItems is non empty then also it is not showing loadingview

Comment: why dont you display footer before you making call to webservice/networking and remove then you get response.. this will get enough time to show it to the user... at-least for 1 sec its visible at any situation.

Comment: @skadoosh thanks , i am already doing the same way, but when response is empty list is becoming empty, so in next request it is not showing footer view

Answer (score 0):

add footer view if your arraylist has data that is binding to your adapter and also check listView.getFooterViewCount before adding if it is already has.